# In Photos, can you crop and scale original to save space?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I often take photos of documents, receipts, or product packaging; to have as a record. These photos usually waste space because they are higher resolution than I need, and they have extra space around edges that can be cropped.

To save space I export the image, scale and crop in Preview, and delete the original from Photos. This is a pain. Can I accomplish the same thing in Photos on macOS?

Comment: What camera / device does the "photo" taking? What scale is your photo library - 50 GB and 4,000 photos or something else. The scale and source affects the optimal solution to your question so I'll refrain from an answer until it's a little more clear if Tetsujin's answer is adequate for what you seek.

Comment: Usually I'm just using my iPhone for these. I have 100s, maybe it's over 1000. I'll probably accept the answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

Any edit will always increase space used, as it will keep the original in Masters & add a new edited version.

It's the 'safest' method which is why I presume it's done that way.

If you want total control over your pictures, you need a more pro-oriented application.

Having said that - my own workflow only uses Photos as a 'show it to people & carry it on the phone' structure. All my real work I do in Photoshop, ViewNX-i etc... but the downside of that is I end up with far more safety copies & work in progress/files with different icc profiles etc than I would if I just used Photos.
One picture can end up having 1GB of variations, + backups in 2 other locations.